# What exactly does stringstream do?

Tags: c++, sstream

I am trying to learn C++ since yesterday and I am using this document: http://www.cplusplus.com/files/tutorial.pdf (page 32). I found a code in the document and I ran it. I tried inputting Rs 5.5 for price and an integer for quantity and the output was 0.
I tried inputting 5.5 and 6 and the output was correct.

```
// stringstreams
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <sstream> 

using namespace std; 

int main () 
{ 
  string mystr; 
  float price = 0; 
  int quantity = 0; 

  cout << "Enter price: "; 
  getline (cin,mystr); 
  stringstream(mystr) >> price; 
  cout << "Enter quantity: "; 
  getline (cin,mystr); 
  stringstream(mystr) >> quantity; 
  cout << "Total price: " << price*quantity << endl; 
  return 0; 
}
```

What exactly does the mystring command do? Quoting from the document:

> "In this example, we acquire numeric values from the standard input
> indirectly. Instead of extracting numeric values  directly from the
> standard input, we get lines from the standard input (cin) into a
> string object (mystr), and then  we extract the integer values from
> this string into a variable of type int (quantity)."

My impression was that the function will take an integral part of a string and use that as input.

Comment: This example is kinda weird, I've never seen `stringstream` used that way. I usually load the line, convert it and then extract by parts, however this obviously has little advantage here because `cin` *is* an input stream already... So `cin >> price >> quantity;` would be by far simpler. That would be a good reason **NOT** to use cplusplus.com tutorials.

Comment: Funny that that tutorial was my first exposure to C++. In hindsight, it's pretty poor and incomplete. I'd suggest a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Maybe they just needed to come up with example to show how `stringstream` works. It is a bizarre one probably even a bad one =) But it shows you can treat string as a stream.

Comment: If it's not an introduction to more advanced uses of `stringstream` then it's definitely a wrong example. And even if it is then it should be written differently.

Comment: From [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/): it's essentially a string buffer that can be used as a stream.

Comment: @trojansdestroy You linked to the page we've just concluded is basically either wrong or obfuscated. Are you even reading?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Is that definition incorrect? I said nothing of the examples on that page. Furthermore, not to disrespect anybody here, but is a list of 25 books a better link? Because I'm sure OP would rather read a few sites, hoping one isn't confusing, than choose a book at random and hope their investment is worthwhile. If it suits you, I'll delete my comment to remove the wrong and obfuscated information.

Comment: @trojansdestroy Why would anyone read "a few sites" instead of books written by respected authors and reviewed by the community is beyond my imagination.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Accessibility. This is a short-term task: understand stringstream. It's easier, cheaper, and faster to read online than to buy a book. Peer-reviewed books are priceless, but better suited for long-term/larger-scope learning.

Comment: @trojansdestroy You can't understand stringstream without understanding all the primitives it's based on, so I don't see how reading a tutorial helps in that regard.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Sometimes it is very convenient to use stringstream to convert between strings and other numerical types. The usage of `stringstream` is similar to the usage of `iostream`, so it is not a burden to learn.

Stringstreams can be used to both read strings and write data into strings. It mainly functions with a string buffer, but without a real I/O channel.

The basic member functions of stringstream class are

- `str()`, which returns the contents of its buffer in string type.
- `str(string)`, which set the contents of the buffer to the string argument.

Here is an example of how to use string streams.

```
ostringstream os;
os << "dec: " << 15 << " hex: " << std::hex << 15 << endl;
cout << os.str() << endl;
```

The result is `dec: 15 hex: f`.

`istringstream` is of more or less the same usage.

To summarize, stringstream is a convenient way to **manipulate strings like an independent I/O device**.

FYI, the inheritance relationships between the classes are:

[image: string stream classes]

Answer (score 28):

From *C++ Primer*:

> The **istringstream** type reads a *string*, **ostringstream** writes a *string*, and **stringstream** reads and writes the *string*.

I come across some cases where it is both convenient and concise to use **stringstream**.

#### case 1

It is from [one of the solutions](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/84382/c-using-stringstream) for [this leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/complex-number-multiplication/#/description). It demonstrates a very suitable case where the use of **stringstream** is efficient and concise.

Suppose `a` and `b` are complex numbers expressed in string format, we want to get the result of multiplication of `a` and `b` also in string format. The code is as follows:

```
string a = "1+2i", b = "1+3i";
istringstream sa(a), sb(b);
ostringstream out;

int ra, ia, rb, ib;
char buff;
// only read integer values to get the real and imaginary part of 
// of the original complex number
sa >> ra >> buff >> ia >> buff;
sb >> rb >> buff >> ib >> buff;

out << ra*rb-ia*ib << '+' << ra*ib+ia*rb << 'i';

// final result in string format
string result = out.str()
```

#### case 2

It is also from a [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/simplify-path/description/) that requires you to simplify the given path string, [one of the solutions using stringstream](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/8678/c-10-lines-solution) is the most elegant that I have seen:

```
string simplifyPath(string path) {
    string res, tmp;
    vector<string> stk;
    stringstream ss(path);
    while(getline(ss,tmp,'/')) {
        if (tmp == "" or tmp == ".") continue;
        if (tmp == ".." and !stk.empty()) stk.pop_back();
        else if (tmp != "..") stk.push_back(tmp);
    }
    for(auto str : stk) res += "/"+str;
    return res.empty() ? "/" : res; 
 }
```

Without the use of stringstream, it would be difficult to write such concise code.

Answer (score 20):

To answer the question. `stringstream` basically allows you to treat a `string` object like a `stream`, and use all `stream` functions and operators on it.

I saw it used mainly for the formatted output/input goodness.

One good example would be `c++` implementation of converting number to stream object.

Possible example:

```
template <class T>
string num2str(const T& num, unsigned int prec = 12) {
    string ret;
    stringstream ss;
    ios_base::fmtflags ff = ss.flags();
    ff |= ios_base::floatfield;
    ff |= ios_base::fixed;
    ss.flags(ff);
    ss.precision(prec);
    ss << num;
    ret = ss.str();
    return ret;
};
```

Maybe it's a bit complicated but it is quite complex. You create `stringstream` object `ss`, modify its flags, put a number into it with `operator<<`, and extract it via `str()`. I guess that `operator>>` could be used.

Also in this example the `string` buffer is hidden and not used explicitly. But it would be too long of a post to write about every possible aspect and use-case.

*Note: I probably stole it from someone on SO and refined, but I don't have original author noted.*

Comment: Note: the use of `ret` is unnecessary, one could write `return ss.str();`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I think I wasn't sure if RVO would kick-in if it was written like that, or if object returned by ss.str() would survive exit point. This way I know I am making a copy, and RVO will work. But you are most probably right.

Comment: Actually, there are 2 forms of RVO: URVO (for unnamed, that is temporaries) and NRVO (for named); most compilers implement RVO, but some restrict it to only URVO (depending on build options). In general, though, there are plenty of other factors to take into account, so you should just write the cleanest code possible and not worry too much about whether RVO will kick in.

Comment: NRVO is common (as is URVO) however it's a non-issue due to move constructors.

Answer (score 2):

You entered an alphanumeric and int, blank delimited in `mystr`.

You then tried to convert the first token (blank delimited) into an `int`.

The first token was RS which failed to convert to `int`, leaving a zero for myprice, and we all know what zero times anything yields.

When you only entered int values the second time, everything worked as you expected.

It was the spurious RS that caused your code to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is convenient to read a line from standard input and parse it later on. I came across a coding problem that ask you to extract last string of each line from input which consists of space separated strings on each line.