# Issue with Converting Double to String in C++

Tags: c++, string

So I know `setprecision(int n)` should be used when printing a double value with precision `n`. However, I've run into a problem on a project that I'm working on that is akin to this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double var = 1.0000001;
    cout << setprecision(10) << var << endl;
    string str = to_string(var);
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
1.0000001
1.000000
```

In the project I'm working on, I need to save the double value as a string, and it will occasionally need more than six decimal places of precision. Here, precision is clearly lost in the conversion. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a reference for [to_string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/). Note that it produces "As many digits are written as needed to represent the integral part, followed by the decimal-point character and six decimal digits".

The rest of the question is a dupe of lots of SO ansers - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332111/how-do-i-convert-a-double-into-a-string-in-c), for example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is std::fixed which is described below:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/

Answer (score 0):

Using `ostringstream` will solve your problem.

```
#include <sstream>

double var = 1.0000001;
ostringstream os;
os << setprecision(10) << var;
string str = os.str();
cout << str << endl; // this should print 1.0000001
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594520/what-exactly-does-stringstream-do